# Updating a ParseUsr

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a problem, as you can see, I'm trying to put new values into existing ParseUser, but It doesnwt change, what have I done wrong?

```
public void updateRating(final double newRating, final double totalRaters2, String username)
{   
    //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(newRating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        ParseUser pu;
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null)
            {
                pu=(ParseUser)(objects.get(0));
                pu.put("totalRaters", totalRaters2);
                pu.put("totalRating", newRating);
                pu.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser p, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Change fetchInBackground to saveInBackground

Comment: I did it,still not working

Comment: Hmm think the problem is permission. You need to be logged in as the user, before being able to edit/update. It would be a huge security issue if any user could update another users information.

Comment: thank you @cYrixmorten, I  I will use ParseObject instead